# EXpectation value of the Poisson distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value, poisson-distribution

I've this homework problem which I do not understand how to solve. A book has 153 pages and number of typos on each page is a `Poisson` random variable with mean $\lambda$, and is independent of the number of typos on all other pages. What is the expected number of pages that do not have a mistake on them?
The expected value of `Poisson` distribution is
$$
P(k;\lambda) = \frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k}} {k!} \quad \langle k \rangle = \lambda = NP \;\; \text{similar to bionomial distribution}
$$
Can someone please provide some hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X_i$ be the random variable describing how many typos there are on page $i$. Then $X_i \sim Poisson(\lambda)$. Then define the random variable $Y_i$ by
$$
Y_i := \begin{cases} 1,\ &\text{if}\ X_i = 0, \\ 0,\ &\text{if}\ X_i>0.\end{cases}
$$
The random variable $Y_i$ describes whether or not there is a typo on page $i$.

Then $Y := \sum_{i=1}^{153} Y_i$ is a random variable describing the number of pages that do not have typos on them. How can you compute $\mathbb{E}(Y)$? The expectation function $\mathbb{E}$ is linear, so:
$$ \begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(Y) &= \mathbb{E}\bigg(\sum_{i=1}^{153} Y_i\bigg) \\[1ex] & = \mathbb{E}(Y_1+Y_2+Y_3+\ldots+Y_{153})\\[1ex] &  = \sum_{i=1}^{153} \mathbb{E}(Y_i) \\[1ex] &  = \mathbb{E}(Y_1) + \mathbb{E}(Y_2) + \mathbb{E}(Y_3) + \ldots + \mathbb{E}(Y_{153})
\end{align}$$
For each $Y_i$, we know $\mathbb{E}(Y_i)=\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)$. Put this together to find your answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I do not get the last line! Did you mean doing average something like this $1/153 + 2/153 + ... 153/153$ ?

Comment: Are you asking about the $\sum$ notation? The sum $\sum_{i=1}^{153} \mathbb{E}(Y_i)$ means $\mathbb{E}(Y_1) + \mathbb{E}(Y_2) + \mathbb{E}(Y_3) + \ldots + \mathbb{E}(Y_{153})$.

Comment: NO! you meant by expectation $\langle E \rangle (Y_{1}) = 1/153$.?

Comment: $\mathbb{P}(X_i=0)$ is the probability mass function of $X_i$ evaluated at $0$. So $\mathbb{P}(X_i=0) = \frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^0}{0!}=e^{-\lambda}$.

Comment: Ok! I get it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The number of pages with no mistakes on them has a Binomial distribution.